# How exactly Arnauld's Paradox is solved in modern mathematics?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, paradoxes

*Wells, David Graham*, The Penguin dictionary of curious and interesting geometry, New York, NY: Penguin Books. xiv, 285 p. (1991). [ZBL0856.00005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0856.00005).

> A friend of Pascal, Antoine Arnauld, argued that if negative numbers 
>   exist, then $$\frac{-1}{1} = \frac{1}{-1}$$ which seems to assert that
>   the ratio  of a smaller to a larger quantity is equal to the ratio of
>   the same larger  quantity to the same smaller.
>
> Most educated adults today would reject this idea after a moment's 
>   thought. No wonder this paradox was discussed at length.

Comment: I guess that the "largness" of a number is determined by its absolute value, not the number itself.

Comment: Especially if we want to consider the size of a quotient of two numbers. This depends on the absolute value of the numerator and the denominator, not on the numbers themselves.
Of course we have to be careful when talking about "size" since I take it to be the absolute value, while Arnauld just takes the value of the number (and that's why this brakes down).

Comment: if that were so, if "largness" were determined by abs value, relations like $\frac{1}{i} = -i$ and $\frac{i}{1} = i$ would be more intuitive.

Comment: "Largness" is not determined ONLY by absolute value. It is determined by absolute value up to a sign. So $\tfrac{a}{b}$ is determined by $|\tfrac{a}{b}|$ and $sign(\tfrac{a}{b})\in \{+1,-1\}$.
This generalizes to Gaussian integers and other irrational numbers by considering, in stead of sign, multiplication by an invertible number. So, in stead of having only $\{+1,-1\}$ , you will have $\{+1,-1,i,-i\}$ to consider as a multiplicative factor. If you consider the whole of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$, then this set of invertibles becomes bigger.

Comment: Arnauld's Paradox is solved in modern Mathematics simply by saying, "Don't be silly."

Answer (score 0):

If one understands the fraction $\frac{m}{n}$ as $m$ resources distributed among $n$ users then we can make the following allegory.

You (1) and your antipode (-1), let's call it wife, share the same bank account with zero balance and saving/kredit features. If you log in once to the account and see that it is a debt of 1 million for you, that is 
$$
\frac{-1}{1}.
$$
It means that your wife has taken 1 million for shopping (positive amount distributed over your antipode)
$$
\frac{1}{-1}.
$$